# How to determine the default printer using WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, printing

To retrieve the list of printers I use:

```
new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections })
```

How do I determine, which of the printers is the default printer?

Note: the `System.Printing.dll` assembly is used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue()
```