# How to create custom Printer Settings Dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

In my WPF project i need to show custom PrinterSetting dialog, i create the needs methods to get all printers list, and i know how to create PrinterSetting class but do not know how to get the selected printer options "Advanced Options" like in Windows8 Metro Document Reader.
please guide me.

like this image: 
"from Windows8"

[image]

Comment: Check the following link: [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912421/printdialog-printersettings-equivalent-in-wpf

Comment: You've posted a screen shot of the Metro print setup, but have tagged your question “WPF”. Those are different, which one do you want? You can get all printer “advanced options” in WPF by clicking “Preferences” in the Print dialog.

Comment: @DourHighArch thanks for your comment, but i meant i want to create my custom PrintDialog in wpf looks like in the Metro.