Set Zebra Label Printer settings in WPF application
I'd like to be able to directly send a window I've designed to look like a label to a printer. The problem I'm having is it's using the default settings for the printer, and I want to modify them directly in my program. The 3 settings I want to modify are Darkness set to 15, Rotate 180, and paper size set to 3 X 1. I have no idea how to get there directly from code. My print method works great when the default settings are already set how I want, unfortunately the printer is used for more than just this so they can't stay the default settings. Any insight is welcome.
private async void DirectPrint()

{
await Task.Delay(250);
string printerName = "ZDesigner GC420d";
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer();
PrintQueueCollection printQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues();
PrintQueue printQueue = printQueues.FirstOrDefault(pq => pq.Name.Contains(printerName));           

if (printQueue != null)
{
    DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size(PrintLayout.ActualWidth, PrintLayout.ActualHeight);
        PrintLayout.Measure(size);
        PrintLayout.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), size));

        VisualBrush brush = new VisualBrush(PrintLayout);
        dc.DrawRectangle(brush, null, new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), size));
    }

    
    PrintTicket printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
    printDialog.PrintQueue = printQueue;
    printDialog.PrintVisual(visual, "Label");

}

}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912421/printdialog-printersettings-equivalent-in-wpf

It's more usual to use zpl and send text to the printer with a zebra label printer.
